# How to run g4 file by ANTLR4 plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, antlr4

I installed ANTLRv4 plugin for my Eclipse and I created a file Hello.g4 :

```
/**
 * Define a grammar called Hello
 */
grammar Hello;

r  : 'hello' ID ;         // match keyword hello followed by an identifier

ID : [a-z]+ ;             // match lower-case identifiers

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

How can I run this g4 file in Eclipse and how to view a parse tree ?

Answer (score 4):

The use of the ANTLR plugin works in two phases: first, you compile the `.g4` file in order to produce the `.java` code for the lexer/parser/visitor/listeners..., then if you open the `Parse Tree` window.

To do that, your project must have the xtext nature, if the nature is not enabled: right click on your project, then `configure->Add Xtext nature`. 
Once the nature is enabled, in the project properties, you should see a `ANTLR4` entry. You can configure special options for your project here.

Each time you will save modifications on your `.g4` (if you have opened it with the ANTLR Editor given with the plugin), this will trigger a recompilation of your files.

To open the `Parse Tree` window, select `Window->Show View->Other...->ANTLR4->Parse Tree`. This will open the window. Now, you have to keep in mind that the ANTLR Editor and the Parse Tree window communicate. In your ANTLR Editor, if you put your cursor on a rule, you will see that the Parse Tree view updates a part of its screen and shows the rule you have selected. You can type your expression and see the parse tree.

Here is what I obtain using your grammar:
[image: Parse Tree and grammar in ANTLR4 Eclipse Plugin]

Comment: wow.it works man
"In your ANTLR Editor, if you put your cursor on a rule, you will the the Parse Tree view updates a part of its screen and show the rule you have selected" -> it helps me so much,thank you
By the way

Comment: i am using Eclipse Luna and also installed plugins: ANTLR4 IDR 0.3.5, AntlrDT 4.3.1, XVisitiorDT 4.3.1, StringTemplateDT 4.3.1. If i select my.g4 file, the Parse Tree view shows blank. i have tried to create as Anltlr Project and also Maven Project or normal Java Project, but no help

Comment: I am using Eclipse nano
eclipse.buildId=4.6.2.M20161124-1400
I'm using the ANTLR4 SDK version 0.3.6.201611052310.
I don't have the ANTLR4 IDR/DT/XVisitor DT, and String Template DT, so I'm going to learn what those are about.
But the parse tree feature doesn't work for me at the moment either.
However these seem to be good instructions!
I did get the Parse Tree View up :).